# How do I get this javascript to apply to all these buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

The first button on the left works perfectly well, and I would like for the other two buttons to work like this as well. I can't figure out how to get the javascript to work for the two buttons on the right. I've been trying to figure this out for awhile and need some help with this code. Thank you in advance!

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".addtocart");
const done = document.querySelector(".done");
console.log(button);
let added = false;
button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  if(added){
    done.style.transform = "translate(-110%) skew(-40deg)";
    added = false;
  }
  else{
    done.style.transform = "translate(0px)";
    added = true;
  }
    
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  outline:none;
}
body,html{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: #dff9fb;
}
.fa-cart-plus{
  background:#0652DD;
}

.addtocart{
  display:block;
  padding:0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius:100px;
  border:none;
  font-size:2em;
  position:relative;
  background:#0652DD;
  cursor:pointer;
  height:2em;
  width:10em;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:transform 0.1s;
  z-index:1;
}
.addtocart:hover{
  transform:scale(1.1);
}
.pretext{
  color:#fff;
  background:#0652DD;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
i{
  margin-right:10px;
}
.done{
  background:#be2edd;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition:transform 0.3s ease;

  transform:translate(-110%) skew(-40deg);
}
.posttext{
  background:#be2edd;
}
.fa-check{
  background:#be2edd;
}
```

```html
<button class="addtocart">
  <div class="pretext">
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> ADD TO CART
  </div>
  
  <div class="pretext done">
    <div class="posttext"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> ADDED</div>
  </div>
</button>


<button class="addtocart">
  <div class="pretext">
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> ADD TO CART
  </div>
  
  <div class="pretext done">
    <div class="posttext"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> ADDED</div>
  </div>
</button>


<button class="addtocart">
  <div class="pretext">
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> ADD TO CART
  </div>
  
  <div class="pretext done">
    <div class="posttext"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> ADDED</div>
  </div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) :

> The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

You have to use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorall):

> The Element method `querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

You are only attaching the event to the first element, you have to get all the elements by using [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorall) and loop through all of them to attach the event individually.

**Working Code Example:**

```js
const buttonList = document.querySelectorAll(".addtocart");

buttonList.forEach(function(button){
  let added = false;
  button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    
    const done = button.querySelector('.done');
    if(added){
      done.style.transform = "translate(-110%) skew(-40deg)";
      added = false;
    }
    else{
      done.style.transform = "translate(0px)";
      added = true;
    }

  });
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  outline:none;
}
body,html{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: #dff9fb;
}
.fa-cart-plus{
  background:#0652DD;
}

.addtocart{
  display:block;
  padding:0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius:100px;
  border:none;
  font-size:2em;
  position:relative;
  background:#0652DD;
  cursor:pointer;
  height:2em;
  width:10em;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:transform 0.1s;
  z-index:1;
}
.addtocart:hover{
  transform:scale(1.1);
}
.pretext{
  color:#fff;
  background:#0652DD;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
i{
  margin-right:10px;
}
.done{
  background:#be2edd;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition:transform 0.3s ease;

  transform:translate(-110%) skew(-40deg);
}
.posttext{
  background:#be2edd;
}
.fa-check{
  background:#be2edd;
}
```

```html
<button class="addtocart">
  <div class="pretext">
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> ADD TO CART
  </div>
  
  <div class="pretext done">
    <div class="posttext"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> ADDED</div>
  </div>
</button>


<button class="addtocart">
  <div class="pretext">
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> ADD TO CART
  </div>
  
  <div class="pretext done">
    <div class="posttext"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> ADDED</div>
  </div>
</button>


<button class="addtocart">
  <div class="pretext">
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> ADD TO CART
  </div>
  
  <div class="pretext done">
    <div class="posttext"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> ADDED</div>
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: this worked. thank you so much for taking the time to help me out and explaining!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to select all the elements by using  `document.querySelectorAll(".addtocart");` and then loop all the elements by for loop here is the updated code

```
const button = document.querySelectorAll(".addtocart");
const done = document.querySelector(".done");
console.log(button);
let added = false;
for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log("clicked")
        if (added) {
            done.style.transform = "translate(-110%) skew(-40deg)";
            added = false;
        }
        else {
            done.style.transform = "translate(0px)";
            added = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace Javascript code to following

```
$(".addtocart").click(function(e){
const style = $(e.currentTarget).find('.done').attr('style');
if(style == undefined || style == 'transform:translate(-110%) skew(-40deg)'){
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.done').attr('style','transform:translate(0px)')
} else{
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.done').attr('style','transform:translate(-110%) skew(-40deg)')
}

});
```